# where is my app

Tags: android

i have copied my .apk to my htc phone's sd card. But, i cannot see the .apk file on the phone (only on my windows machine) so i cannot install it? Anyone have any

Comment: What exactly are the steps you've taken to "see" the apk on your phone? And what leads you to believe that those steps should result your expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

[How to install APK's](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/37151.aspx)

What apps are you using to try and find it?  Do you have an SD browser and you can't find it? Do you have an APK installer?

This is the one I use, and it's free and works fine:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.android.apkinstaller&feature=search_result

Answer (score 0):

How are you looking for it?
Maybe you can load a file-browser like Astro and look for it?

Answer (score 0):

Some File browsers if they have all ready been opened once when you copy something on the SD card you need to tell the app to refresh which can normally be found somewhere in the menu.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing your app with ADB instead of copying it to your machine?

adb install packagename.apk

Answer (score 0):

You can try out SuperManager to locate the apk from the sdcard directory and install it.
Check out its other functions:
https://market.android.com/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.TaskManager&feature=search_result

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the suggestions!
turns out it was a bad sd card  .. or atleast once a different card was loaded i sould see the app & install it ..

i use no special software for this, just copy the .apk from windows to the phone .. 
i then see it under the sd card option for viewing apps & can install it from there.

thanks agian!